# Noughts and Crosses: replace numbers on the board with an empty space

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am developing a noughts and crosses game and I have to create a code to set all elements of the board to one space `'  '`

All integers have to be replaced by an empty space so when I print the output, it will show an empty board.

See the picture below for reference. The code I used for a populated board is as follows:

```
def draw_board(board):

    # Display board
    board = ["1", "2", "3",
             "4", "5", "6",
             "7", "8", "9"]
    print(" ----------- ")
    print("| " + board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2] + " | ")
    print(" ----------- ")
    print("| " + board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5] + " | ")
    print(" ----------- ")
    print("| " + board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8] + " | ")
    print(" ----------- ")
    text = "When prompted, enter the number corresponding to the square you want."
    print(text)

    pass
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3YcL.png)

I've tried using `join()`, `.split`, `.replace`, and `.append` however, after 2 days and lots of time spent researching I couldn't figure out how to replace the numbers inside the list with an empty space.

Almost everything I tried returned a `typeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

I just want to print out the board without the numbers or hyphens.
I should also mention I'm a newbie at this so any help is much appreciated!

So I managed to fix it, which is great! However, another issue has arisen: see image [emptyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAECl.png)

Comment: What issue you are facing now? `Line 31` can't be seen on a screen.

Comment: Hey Albina, after printing the empty board this also appears [ '  ' ], sorry I posted a picture of it but didn't name the hyperlink appropriately, you can see it underneath the empty board. The traceback message is ok, is only because I have functions there which I haven't used yet.

Comment: So you should have spaces in the `board` instead of numbers. Or just print spaces instead of `board[0]`, `board[1]`, etc.

Comment: Some code calls to print this empty array `['', ..., '']` after the grid on a screen (before you call a method `draw_board()`). You should check your code or at least show it to us :)

Comment: Thank you both for the fast responses, I removed the numbers on the board and replaced them with ' ' in order to print it out empty. Figured it out 10 min after posting but I didn't want to delete it as it may help someone else.